# Simple way to add rowspan in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to generate a HTML Table, that has rowSpan (as you see in the picture)
I manage to generate the table for columns 1 and 2 and 3. Here is the code:

```
 <td rowspan="2"> a</td> 
                    <td>bb</td> 
                    <td>d</td> 
                </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>e</td>
                    </tr>
```

but when it gets to column4, I can't figure out what to do. I create a nested table but it doesn't work properly.
Anyone has any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this - the first column spans 3 rows, the middle columns span just a single row, and the top right column is again 2 rows spanned:

```
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">a</td>
    <td rowspan="2">b</td>
    <td rowspan="2">c</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
    <td>j</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://jsfiddle.net/gpnx0nqj/

Note that the second row only have two cells (`td`).